# Where is the color background coming from?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm displaying a link

```html
<li>
    <a id="bilg" href="phonelist_5.cfm?bilingual">
        <img src="icon-bilingual2.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" style="margin-bottom:-3px;  display: inline-block;" />
        Bilingual
    </a>
</li>
```

IE is showing a color background not part of the image (confirmed with `Images\Disable images`).

[image]

The background color is only showing in IE — not Chrome/Firefox.

I have seen all the CSS and nothing is showing that specific color.

How can I find out where is getting this background color from?

Comment: If you can't, how can *we* find out when we don't have the full working(!) example?

Comment: As Mörre said, we need to see a working demo (such as on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)), and what the correct image is before we can help you.

Comment: ***a img { border: 0; }* should eliminate unwanted image border.**

Comment: probably link boreder.

Answer (score 2):

#### Internet Explorer 10 and below

*Update: It appears you are using an older version of Internet Explorer's developer tools. You won't have the option to "Inspect Element", so you'll need to locate the element once you have pressed F12 and opened the tools to begin with. Also, use TraceStyles in the place of Computed when performing the second step.*

[image]

#### Internet Explorer 11

In order to quickly locate where a particular style is coming from, right-click the element and select *Inspect Element*. This brings up your developer tools, with the DOM Explorer selected. You may need to use the DOM Explorer to more accurately adjust your selection at this point.

With your element selected in the DOM Explorer, select the **Styles** panel on the right of your developer tools. This shows the full cascade of styles on your element from all stylesheets. From here you would look either for *background* related properties, or perhaps *border* properties. If a property is not crossed-out, that means it is presently applied to the element. The selector and file are also listed above the applied property:

[image]

This view may be a bit noisy; if that is the case, switch over to the **Computed** tab to see a list of all currently applied styles listed in alphabetical order. You'll see a toggle in the top-right that shows *all* styles (including those from the browser) or merely user styles. From here, locate the relevant properties (such as *background* and/or *border* properties) to see if they are defined someplace, or inhereited from the user-agent stylesheet.

[image]

Using these two views should help you determine where your "color background" (which may not be a *background*) is coming from; specifically which line, selector, and source file. If you share a working demo of your code, I'm sure myself or somebody else here would be able to further assist you.